# secondary axis of an indexed variable & same axis for multiple plots produced in a loop - in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have 12 panels of monthly data. Each panels x-axis is a unique id that combines two variables (Vc and Vw). Each panels y-axis is a unique id that combines two variables (Rc and Rw). The length of the vector of the number of combinations for Vc and Vw (VGroupid) VGroupid is the same for each month. The length of the vector of combinations of Rc and Rw (RGroupid) changes per month. The result of choosing each of several RGroupid per VGroupid is displayed as one of several benefits (0,13,26, or 36). These benefits are differentiated with colors. The data for each month was created in a for loop. THe results for each month are appended to each other into a list. The list is then melted into four categories, "VGroupid","variable" (which is the RGroupid), "value" (which is the benefit i mentioned earlier) and "month."

For example,

```
Vc=c(0,10e6,2*10e6) 
Vw=c(0,10e6,2*10e6)
VGroupid =c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9) such that 
VcinVGroupid = c(0,0,0,10e6,10e6,10e6,2*10e6,2*10e6,2*10e6) 
VwinVGroupid = c(0,10e6,2*10e6,0,10e6,2*10e6,0,10e6,2*10e6)
[So VGroupid==1 is Vc==0 and Vw==0]
Rc_Jun=c(0,10e6,2*10e6)
Rw_Jun=c(0,10e6,2*10e6)
RGroupid_Jun=seq(1,9,1)
Rc_May=c(0,10e6,2*10e6)
Rw_May=c(0,10e6)
Rc_April=c(0,10e6)
Rw_April={} (empty set, no options)

An extremely small sample of dplot=
  VGroupid variable value    month
          1        2    36     April
          2        2    36     April
          1        1    36     April
          2        1    36     April
          3        2    36     April
          1        2    36     April
         6       2     0       May
         5       3     0       May
         5       4     13       May
         5       5     26       May
         1        1     0      June
         2        1     36      June
         6        1     26      June
         1        2     13      June
         9        1     0      June
         8        9     36      June
         6        8     26      June
         7        7     13      June

ggplot(dplot, aes(VGroupid, variable, group=factor(month), color=factor(value)), size=3)+ 
  geom_point()   +
  facet_grid(. ~month)
```

I have the data displayed with 12 plots paneled using facet_grid in ggplot2. It looks pretty. The labels need help and scaling need help. Questions:
1. How do I replace the x-axis label for each plot to be 2 x-axes, one for each of the two variables that make up VGroupid. So instead of having VGroupid, I want to actually display values for Vc and Vw. I need to do this same action for the y-axis to replace RGroupid with the actual Rc and Rw values. With only one ggplot2 I can use the annotate function for this, but this function does not work with multiple plots with facet_grid. 
2. Each plot has a different length of RGroupid (the y-axis is not the same length for each plot). How can I display each plot with a different y-axis?

For Question #1: with one ggplot2 of just one month, I can use the following code to create the axes, but this is not transferable to a 12 plot panel:
  #axes

```
annotate("text", x=-0.25, y=seq(1,length(Rwdecs), 1), label=Rc, color="blue", 
    size=2.25)+ #http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/annotate.html
annotate("text", x=Vwscale, y=0.5, label=Vc, color="blue", size=2.25)+
  if(Rw>0){scale_y_discrete(labels=Rwdecs)
  } else{theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
               axis.text.y=element_blank(),
               axis.ticks.y=element_blank())}+
  if(Rw>0){scale_x_discrete(labels=Vw)
  } else{theme(axis.title.x=element_blank(),
               axis.text.x=element_blank(),
               axis.ticks.x=element_blank())}
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take at tour at https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 0):

Solutions:

Question 1 answer: I guess ggplot2 has declared no secondary axes unless the secondary axis is a function of the primary - which normally makes sense but in my case, since the secondary axes is *not* a function of the primary. The two axes combine to make an index. The index (e.g. the same point has two y axis identifiers). Sad that the secondary axis function is not available for this like with R  plots. Solution: I concatenated the indices on the primary axis. Text looks sloppy but it works:

p+scale_y_continuous(breaks=DisplaysR[,3],labels=paste(DisplaysR[,1],DisplaysR[,2],sep=","))

Question2 answer: I answered my question by first discovering the 2018 R studio version of ggplot2 cheat sheet: rstudio.com/resources/cheatsheets converting my data from factor to numeric: stackoverflow.com/questions/29278153/… , so all the y axis observations are on the same scale. with this all data were in the multiplots were displayed on the same scale, which i originally limited with scale_y_continuous(limits= min and max of RGroupid) - but then found that it is actually better to set breaks and labels and use the scale_y_continuous command:

p+scale_y_continuous(breaks=DisplaysR[,3],labels=paste(DisplaysR[,1],DisplaysR[,2],sep=",")) + #GlobalRoptions[2,]) +
scale_x_continuous(breaks=seq(1,15,1), labels=paste(Voptions[,1], Voptions[,2], sep=","))